# Не удалось загрузить библиотеку jshint в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jshint

В VS Code скачала jshint. 
После этого выдает ошибку: Failed to load jshint library. Please install jshint in your workspace folder using 'npm install jshint' or globally using 'npm install -g jshint' and then press Retry. - Не удалось загрузить библиотеку jshint. 
Перевод: Пожалуйста, установите у JSHint в рабочей области папки с помощью 'НПМ установить у JSHint или глобально, используя 'НПМ установки -G и у JSHint и затем нажмите кнопку Повторить.
Что сделано:
1.Добавила файл jshintrc в общую рабочую папку.
2. В терминале прописала варианты npm install jshint и npm install -g jshint (увидела как вариант, когда искала ответ в инете.) Сделала скрин ошибки.
Вопрос:
Как исправить ошибку,чтобы jshint работал, прошу, напишите по пунктам?

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя пишет "npm не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом". Отсюда у меня возникает вопрос, установлен ли у тебя Node.js, если нет, то тебе нужно скачать его на **nodejs.org**

Comment: Вы правы. Благодарю Вас. Это решило мою проблему.

Comment: У меня node.js установлен, но ошибка не пропадает